# Unable to produce the value of lat and lng using any state

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script using requests module to get the name of different brokers from a [webpage](https://www.ibba.org/state/alabama/). This is the [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7VHQ.jpg) that I chose to produce results. Althought the following script can parse the names out of that populated results from that site, I can't figure out how I can produce the value of `lat` and `lng` that I've used in `params`.

As I wish to parse names from few states, it is necessary that I use the value of `lat` and `lng` programmatically. Currently they are hardcoded.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://www.ibba.org/wp-json/brokers/geo'
params = {
    'lat': '40.3607',
    'lng': '-74.3693',
    'miles': '250',
    'specialties': '',
    'cbi': ''
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    for item in res.json()['features']:
        print(item['geometry']['properties']['name'])
```

> How can I produce the value of `lat` and `lng` using any state required to be used within params?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the latitude and longitude given the name of the state? A dictionary seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, right you are. Using any state or any zip code, as in `77007`?

Comment: I think you're asking whether there's a way to acquire data based on either state or zip code. If that's the case then you need to refer to the API's documentation which will (presumably) tell you what query parameters are permitted. After that, it's going to be a question of whether the longitude and latitude data are returned in the JSON response. It appears that the response does include a coordinates key but based on your sample lat and lng values they don't match exactly. Of course, the API implementation may be basing its search on 'nearest match'

Comment: You can try using the [pgeocode library](https://pypi.org/project/pgeocode/) to get lat/lon from zipcodes.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for @Jack Fleeting. Please post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question you have has to do with finding a source for lat/lon coordinates, given a zip code. It's not as trivial as it should be, but fortunately [the pgeocode library](https://pypi.org/project/pgeocode/) can handle the task in python.